# Using induction to verify the formula for a summation $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

> **Problem 4.** use the principle of induction to verify:
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

[image]

base case is obviously easy, but I don't know how to prove the inductive case

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435412/induction-proof-sum-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16)

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\right) + (n+1)^2.$$ Use the induction hypothesis on the first term.

Comment: @DavidMitra  thank you. where does the + (m+1)^2 term come from for P(m+1) though? I don't understand that.

Comment: oh duh, that's k^2 = (n+1)^2, we're adding just that last term...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+(n+1)^2=(n+1)\left(\frac{n(2n+1)}6+n+1\right)=$$

$$=(n+1)\left(\frac{n(2n+1)+6n+6}6\right)=\frac{n+1}6(n+2)(2n+3)\ldots\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this has been answered before on this site, but anyway here's the proof:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + (n+1)^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + (n+1)^2$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1) + 6(n+1)^2}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2 = \frac{(n+1)((2n^2+n) + 6(n+1))}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2n+3)(n+2)}{6}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2(n+1)+1)((n+1)+1)}{6}$$

Comment: I don't understand: how did you get from the third step to the fourth? how can you add those: the first term is in a multiplication right?

Comment: @furashu I missed one parenthesis, maybe that's the reason why you didn't get it.

Comment: oh thank you, it makes sense now.