# Induction Proof: $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

Prove by induction, the following: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$ So this is what I have so far:

We will prove the base case for $n=1$: $$\sum_{k=1}^1 1^2 = \frac{1(1+1)(2(1)+1)}6$$ We can see this is true because $1=1$.

Using induction we can assume the statement is true for $n$, we want to prove the statement holds for the case $n+1$: 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 :& =\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + (n+1)^2\\ 
& = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 + (n+1)^2 && \text{by I.H}\\ 
& = \frac{(n+6)(2n+1)(n+1)^3}6 && \text{algebra}
\end{align*}

This is as far as I have gotten in the proof I know that I am almost there, but I am wondering if I missed a step or did the algebra wrong.  I know that what I'm supposed to get is $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}6$ or is that incorrect too?  This should be fairly simple, but for some reason it just isn't working for me.

Comment: Your "algebra" step is wrong. There's no way to turn the sum of a cubic polynomial and a quadratic polynomial into a fifth-degree polynomial. It looks like you multiplied them, almost.

Comment: BTW you can find several posts about this proof on this site. For example: [induction proof: $\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435412/induction-proof-sum-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing details of your "algebra" step, it is hard to be more specific. Start with: $$\begin{align}
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+(n+1)^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + \frac{6(n+1)^2}{6} \\
&= \frac{n+1}{6}(n(2n+1) +6(n+1))
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for that step.  I think my brain just gave up, it's always the simple stuff lol.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 :=\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2} + (n+1)^2$$ $$=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6 + (n+1)^2 \quad\text{by Induction hypothesis}$$ 
$$=(n+1)\Big(\frac{n(2n+1)}{6}+(n+1)\Big)$$
$$=(n+1)\Big(\frac{2n^2+n+6n+6}{6}\Big)$$
$$=(n+1)\Big(\frac{2n^2+7n+6}{6}\Big)$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+3)}{6}$$

Comment: Your factorization of $2n^2 + 7n + 6$ is incorrect.  To split the linear term, you need two numbers with product $2 \cdot 6 = 12$ and sum $7$.

Comment: Yeah ! a small typo was there

Answer (score 1):

This is not an induction proof but might be useful by way of enrichment.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^n \binom {2k}2+\binom {2k+1}2=\frac14\sum_{j=1}^{2n}\binom {j+1}2\\\\
=\frac 14 \binom {2n+2}3=\frac 16n(n+1)(2n+1)\qquad\blacksquare$$